# The function isn't repeating in the way i want it to

Tags: c#, file, directory

So I am trying to add strings to a hashtable then write it on a text file but it's only printing one line, not the other five.

When I try writing it on the console it works perfectly fine.

I'm very new to using files so I'm not sure on the problem`public static int number = 1;

```
    static void using_integers_also_arrays(string val)
    {
        user3 = new Hashtable();
        using (StreamWriter Path = new StreamWriter("file"))
        {
            while (number < 5)
            {
                number += 1;
                user3.Add(number, val);
                Path.WriteLine($"Username: {user3[number]}");
                Path.WriteLine(number);
                Console.WriteLine($"Username: {user3[number]}");
                
                using_integers_also_arrays(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            if (number >= 5)
            {
                Path.WriteLine("finished");
            }
        }

    }
    static Hashtable user3;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        

            using_integers_also_arrays(Console.ReadLine());
 

    }`
```

Comment: Any exceptions?

Comment: So, what happens when you try to execute that code?

Comment: it only shows the first line but on the console it works the way I want it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, you're trying to ask the user for new input when you haven't even closed the file.
So, you have to move this line to outside of the using code block.

```
using_integers_also_arrays(Console.ReadLine());
```

Like this:

```
using (StreamWriter Path = new StreamWriter("file", true))
        {
            while (number < 5)
            {
                number += 1;
                user3.Add(number, val);
                Path.WriteLine($"Username: {user3[number]}");
                Path.WriteLine(number);
                Console.WriteLine($"Username: {user3[number]}");
            }
            if (number >= 5)
            {
                Path.WriteLine("finished");
            }
        }
                
                using_integers_also_arrays(Console.ReadLine());
```

EDIT: As @Johnny Andrew pointed out on the other answer, you must also use the true parameter overload to avoid rewriting the content each time.
This way, you get the 5 lines from the user input and also allows you to append more content to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think by calling new StreamWriter("file"), you overwrite its content each time, that's why you end up with 1 line in that file.

In this case, you must pass a second parameter when creating the stream writer in order to append. Take a look at microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_

Try this:

```cs
...
using (StreamWriter Path = new StreamWriter("file", true))
...
```

Comment: I tried the code and it doesn't even write to the file because it only writes when you close it, which he doesn't do. He tries to ask for new user input inside the using block. So the file doesn't get closed or written into. And there comes the file being in use exception...

Comment: You are right, must close the stream writer before opening another. But in order to append to the file in the next  using_integers_also_arrays(Console.ReadLine()); StreamWriter must be opened with the true parameter, else the file would still end up with 1 line written only